# Autoit launches batchfile passing variable

Tags: autoit

I'm currently trying to create an installation tool. I have a a batch file calling some sqlcmd commands and I'd like to trigger it from Autoit. It works.

Now, I'd like to set a variable in Autoit (by getting it from a GUI) and pass it to the batch file when calling it. It should be something like this :

```
  RunWait('path_of_file\mybat.bat' & %myVar%)
```

I read a lot from the Autoit community without finding the answer. I got things like :

```
 RunWait('path_of_file\mybat.bat' & " " & $myVar) <- This solution didn't work for me
```

or

```
 RunWait(@ComSpec & " /k "...)  <- This one didn't suit what I'd like to do, as I'm 
                                   launching a batchfile and not a cmd command.
```

If anyone has an idea !

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

Autoit works

```
 Local $myVar = "ipconfig"
 RunWait('mybat.bat ' & $myVar)
```

Autoit works too

```
 ShellExecute("mybat.bat", $myVar)
```

mybat.bat

```
@echo off
echo %1
%1
ping 127.0.0.1 -n 6 > nul
```

Comment: It's perfect ! Thanks a lot !

Comment: I don't feel it's useful to open a new topic for it, but what if I'd like to use 2 parameters or more ? ShellExecute("mybat.bat", $myVar, $myVar2) seems not working.

Comment: Just have a look here https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/124245-shellexecute-with-parameters/